# Linear Algebra Geometry

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, vector-analysis

Find the vector, point normal and general forms of the equations of the plane passing through point $P = (1, 0, -1)$ and having $\mathbf n = (5, 1, -2)$ as a normal.

Is there one vector equation? I just find different for different vectors is it normal?

Comment: $\mathbf n\cdot \mathbf x=\mathbf n\cdot \mathbf P$

Comment: Your question is specifically on the vector form?

Comment: Yes, on the vector form only